# TLS - Cert Hostname DOES NOT VERIFY

Tags: email, ssl, ubuntu-10.04, plesk

After an SSL certificate change on my virtual server running plesk and ubuntu I suddenly run into an email issue.

Cert Hostname DOES NOT VERIFY (`mail.koemanmotoren.nl != www.koemanmotoren.nl`)
http://www.checktls.com/perl/TestReceiver.pl

mail: e.g. `kleding@koemanmotoren.nl`

Indeed this site seems to verify that the hostname is `mail.koemanmotoren.nl`
https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=koemanmotoren.nl

However I have changed every single hostname I could find, while changing it in plesk or via SSH it automatically changes it anyway everywhere, but somewhere must been another hostname noted?

The certificate is purchased and verified for `koemanmotoren.nl` and `www.koemanmotoren.nl`

Comment: Just wondering the purpose of this question. Are you doing this when setting up a development environment, or is this purely a system administration problem?

Comment: im a web designer, there for my technical server knowledge aint the best. However I've decided some years back to use my own virtual server to host most websites on to have more freedom, this lately means also hours and hours fixing stuff, updates, security issues w/e

Comment: OK, I was just asking because some people might consider it off-topic, since it doesn't seem primarily about development. This being said, setting up a development environment could arguably be on topic... There are different opinions on this.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you are using the same certificate on `mail.koemanmotoren.nl` and `www.koemanmotoren.nl` (see below). Both Subject Key Identifiers are `26:61:81:B0...4A:F8:4F:5B`.

It looks like your DNS is incorrect. You are using the same IP address for both `mail.koemanmotoren.nl` and `www.koemanmotoren.nl`.

```
$ dig mail.koemanmotoren.nl a

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mail.koemanmotoren.nl.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mail.koemanmotoren.nl.  21164   IN  A   176.28.10.250
```

And:

```
$ dig www.koemanmotoren.nl a
...

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.koemanmotoren.nl.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.koemanmotoren.nl.   21223   IN  A   176.28.10.250
```

If that's correct, then the certificate is missing a Subject Alternative Name (SAN) for `mail.koemanmotoren.nl`.

---

According to DNS, your mail server is `mail.koemanmotoren.nl`:

```
$ dig koemanmotoren.nl mx
...

;; ANSWER SECTION:
koemanmotoren.nl.   21219   IN  MX  10 mail.koemanmotoren.nl.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
mail.koemanmotoren.nl.  13180   IN  A   176.28.10.250
```

However, it appears your mail server is using your web server's certificate.

```
$ openssl s_client -connect mail.koemanmotoren.nl:993 2>&1 | openssl x509 -text -noout

        Subject: OU=Domain Control Validated, CN=www.koemanmotoren.nl
        ...
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:www.koemanmotoren.nl, DNS:koemanmotoren.nl
                ...
```

And it appears you don't have anything on 465:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect mail.koemanmotoren.nl:465
CONNECTED(00000003)
140735144829404:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol:s23_clnt.c:787:
---
no peer certificate available
---
...
```

---

```
$ openssl s_client -connect mail.koemanmotoren.nl:443 2>&1 | openssl x509 -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            11:21:13:40:67:18:79:8f:1d:3f:c5:48:48:f4:2c:f1:24:b6
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=BE, O=GlobalSign nv-sa, CN=GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - SHA256 - G2
        Validity
            Not Before: Jun 10 11:20:11 2014 GMT
            Not After : Jul 15 10:12:25 2015 GMT
        Subject: OU=Domain Control Validated, CN=www.koemanmotoren.nl
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:eb:cf:e0:55:34:52:79:43:8b:49:1b:65:1c:b1:
                    ed:ad:93:52:12:b9:3a:55:d7:c2:10:10:cc:3f:2c:
                    e0:11:9a:4b:5b:ba:eb:3b:5f:f7:ad:74:e2:15:ba:
                    04:14:bc:52:84:ce:4b:a3:e7:a5:48:45:0f:09:cc:
                    b9:98:2d:1c:0a:00:75:0d:d0:ac:d6:88:52:5b:50:
                    fb:bb:10:8b:8d:17:ce:1b:ba:61:23:46:7e:77:70:
                    0e:d4:89:17:bb:2a:76:62:17:d9:12:ae:7a:1d:8e:
                    f1:b6:ff:f3:53:76:cd:74:fb:c9:c4:99:27:c8:4c:
                    5d:9d:07:53:53:d5:16:42:f5:0f:cd:75:01:82:20:
                    05:07:d6:19:a7:9d:77:85:84:97:cb:61:5a:f9:10:
                    d1:88:e4:7c:09:97:8c:9a:c1:4f:b9:a6:bf:57:87:
                    ab:87:59:01:fa:48:3f:86:5e:fe:15:49:8c:32:de:
                    6b:01:23:ea:6c:d3:fc:77:f8:c5:3f:41:89:18:74:
                    1b:44:87:b8:76:e4:cd:b8:be:33:0b:71:7d:4e:7f:
                    83:0a:46:7e:ef:63:ce:0a:20:7e:7c:aa:2a:d4:82:
                    af:95:a9:29:3d:13:e6:52:51:f2:74:ef:93:70:d9:
                    71:9b:1f:19:a5:d0:f7:9e:cc:c8:3d:63:6a:a6:35:
                    7c:75
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Certificate Policies: 
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1
                  CPS: https://www.globalsign.com/repository/

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name: 
                DNS:www.koemanmotoren.nl, DNS:koemanmotoren.nl
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: 
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://crl.globalsign.com/gs/gsdomainvalsha2g2.crl

            Authority Information Access: 
                CA Issuers - URI:http://secure.globalsign.com/cacert/gsdomainvalsha2g2r1.crt
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp2.globalsign.com/gsdomainvalsha2g2

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                26:61:81:B0:89:19:AF:DC:BE:01:DC:59:C1:28:F0:D4:4A:F8:4F:5B
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:EA:4E:7C:D4:80:2D:E5:15:81:86:26:8C:82:6D:C0:98:A4:CF:97:0F

    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
         7a:84:d6:2e:31:44:25:95:aa:d0:30:b6:2e:8c:1b:a9:a3:f3:
         2e:f3:9c:0d:cf:a9:51:29:5f:39:ac:f2:1d:4b:f7:e0:50:05:
         bf:b6:51:f1:0b:a9:43:42:32:9e:40:45:f3:e9:a7:7a:97:7e:
         aa:80:c6:0f:f3:89:5c:87:d4:51:c3:44:a1:55:0a:16:3f:66:
         8e:1e:af:74:95:18:98:ef:be:08:e5:20:f0:b2:20:4c:88:8e:
         8b:00:c3:5d:0b:aa:cc:b6:80:23:83:3a:24:83:8d:fa:13:14:
         bf:76:be:60:d0:c8:ce:6e:8d:22:01:90:0f:f4:5e:fa:d6:80:
         25:e9:ff:d6:07:1d:95:41:4b:74:c2:a7:a3:e3:02:c4:d3:77:
         3e:c9:e2:71:49:ba:4b:71:f8:92:0d:92:24:72:3c:ac:47:ef:
         5e:54:2b:c4:ed:5c:78:9d:75:17:f5:7f:23:bd:af:ee:35:4a:
         54:0e:72:00:45:45:0a:be:8f:ba:d5:3b:18:f9:8b:e0:0a:25:
         74:76:21:01:67:50:6a:0b:7a:3c:fb:c4:b5:ab:f5:01:56:97:
         8f:28:d0:28:54:0c:38:5d:7d:36:8d:89:6b:27:62:dd:93:e2:
         ea:7f:88:e8:cb:df:0b:4c:74:19:1f:7e:be:54:08:6b:85:e0:
         28:52:c9:d7
```

Comment: thanks jww, appreciate it. I have deleted the A mail. entry in the DNS template, should take a while now to take the change. Hope that was it then.

Comment: Still strange why Qualys SSl (https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=koemanmotoren.nl) shows mail.x.nl as hostname tho, but guess thats another topic then, as long as it works.

Comment: If you want to see your mail record, try `dig koemanmotoren.nl mx`. It points to `mail.koemanmotoren.nl`. But it looks like your mail server is using your web server's certificate: `openssl s_client -connect mail.koemanmotoren.nl:993 2>&1 | openssl x509 -text -noout`.

Comment: @uniqueHH Server hostname in the Qualys SSL Labs page has nothing to do with your certificate, it's the reverse lookup of your server's IP address: this is not related to verifying the identity of the server certificate.

Comment: Copy that, its just that i am confused by its saying that mail.koemanmotoren.nl is my hostname. But indeed it seems the DNS settings most likely. After like 2 hours i guess to got it right.
http://www.intodns.com/koemanmotoren.nl
Still one thing left:
smtp  koemanmotoren.nl  Warning - Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner 
but i have set the right DNS entry for it i believe. 
Gotta continue tomorrow, thanks for your input guys, rly appreciated.